# Counting commutative columns in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have pairwise strings like this in my file

```
A B
A C
B A
B C
C A
```

I'm looking for a way to count how many commutative pairs I got. I.e `A B` and `B A` makes one such pair but `B C` doesn't (because we miss `C B`).

I have tried working with awk but I'm just guessing at this point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can any pair (e.g. `A B`) appear more than once? Can there be a "pair" with duplicate values, e.g. `A A`? If either of those can occur then include them in your sample input/output.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it

```
awk '{if ($2<$1) print $2" "$1; else print $1" "$2}' |sort filenames.* | uniq -d |wc -l
```

First part of the code will sort the file, then we remove duplicates.

Comment: Piping `awk`'s output to `sort filesnames.*` looks wrong. Did you mean `awk ... filenames* | sort | ...`? And switching the positions of `$1` and `$2` this way would count 2x `A B` as a pair.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{seen[$1,$2]++} seen[$2,$1]{cnt++} END{print cnt+0}' file
2
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative `awk` which counts the imbalances between commutative pairings

```
awk '{if (com[$2"/"$1]>0){com[$2"/"$1]--}else{com[$1"/"$2]++}}
 END{print "Unbalanced commutations";for (c in com) if (com[c]>0){print c, com[c]; un=un+com[c]} print "and "(NR-un)/2" commutated pairs"}' file1
```

Output

```
Unbalanced commutations
B/C 1
and 2 commutated pairs
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below script and worked perfectly

```
for i in "A B" "B C" "C A"; do j=`echo $i | rev`;  p=`awk -v i="$i" -v j="$j" '$0 ~ i||$0 ~ j{if(!seen[$0]++)print }' filename|wc -l` ; if [[ $p == "2" ]] ;then echo "match found for $i"; awk -v i="$i" -v j="$j" '$0 ~ i||$0 ~ j{if(!seen[$0]++)print }' l1; else echo "match didnt found for $i";fi;echo "==============================================================";done
```

output

```
match found for A B
A B
B A
==============================================================
match didnt found for B C
==============================================================
match found for C A
A C
C A
==============
```